# Ruby: Retrieve local variable from class

Tags: ruby

I was reading up on metaprogramming and came across this exercise:

http://ruby-metaprogramming.rubylearning.com/html/Exercise_1.html

The question is:

Given this class definition:

```
class A
  def initialize
    @a = 11
    @@a = 22
    a = 33
  end
  @a = 1
  @@a = 2
  a = 3
end
```

Retrieve all the variables from outside the class, with output like so:

```
1
2
3
11
22
33
```

Now, it's pretty straightforward to get the instance and class variables dynamically, even the local variable inside the constructor (it's the return value of the initialize method). But I'm stumped as to how to get the local variables `a=3`.

As far as I know, this is not possible because the local variables cease to exist after the class definition is first read.

The only roundabout way that I have made this work is to set a variable to the "return" value (for lack of a better term) of when the class is declared, like so:

```
val = class A
  a = 3
end

puts val # => 3
```

Is this the only way?

Comment: You could try defining `def a=(val)` at class level. That would capture it, but not sure how you'd  make it work like a normal local assignment too.

Answer (score 2):

The question seems to boil down to this: given the following:

```
class A
  attr_reader :instance_var
  def initialize
    @instance_var = (@instance_var ||= 0) + 1
    instance_local_var = 33
    puts "instance_local_variables = #{ local_variables }"
    instance_local_var = 33
  end
  class_local_var = 3
  puts "class_local_variables = #{ local_variables }"
  class_local_var = 3
end
  # class_local_variables = [:class_local_var]
  #=> 3
```

can one determine the values of `instance_local_var` and `class_local_var`?

**Determine the value of `class_local_var`**

The answer to this question is clearly "no" because `class_local_var` no longer exists (has been marked for garbage collection) after `end` is executed<sup>1</sup>:

```
A.send(:local_variables)
  #=> []
```

**Determine the value of `instance_local_var`**

```
a = A.new
  # instance_local_variables = [:instance_local_var]
  #=> #<A:0x007ff3ea8dbb80 @instance_var=1>
```

Note that `@instance_var #=> 1`.

`A.new` does not return the value of `instance_local_var`, but because that variable is assigned a value in the last line of `initialize`, that value can be obtained by executing `initialize` once again.<sup>2</sup>

```
instance_local_var = a.send(:initialize)
  #=> 33
```

There is a problem, however:

```
a.instance_var
  #=> 2
```

Executing `initialize` a second time has caused an unwanted side effect. My definition of `initialize` is artificial, but it highlights the fact that many undesirable side effects could occur by executing `initialize` a second time.

Now let's obtain a new instance.

```
b = A.new
  # instance_local_variables = [:instance_local_var]
  #=> #<A:0x007fee0996e7c8 @instance_var=1>
```

Again, `@instance_var=1`. One possible workaround to the side-effects of calling `initialize` twice for a given instance is to subclass `A` and use `super`.

```
class B < A
  attr_reader :b
  def initialize
    @b = super
  end
end

B.new.b
  #=> 33
a.instance_var
  #=> 1
```

There is no guarantee that undesirable side-effects can be avoided with this approach (e.g., `initialize` for any instance may perform a database operation that should occur only once), but it appears to leave the initial instance `a` unaffected. This is of course all hypothetical.

<sup>1. `send` must be used because `A.private_methods.include?(:local_variables) #=> true`</sup>

<sup>2. `A.new.send(:initialize)` is required because `iniitialize` is private.</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Your question is unclear. In the title, you write "local variables", but in the example, you mention only instance- and class-variables.

As for the instance variables, you can use Object#instance_variables to get a list of known instance variables at this point. Note however that instance variables are created dynamically, not at the time of class declaration. For example, given the class

```
class AA; 
  def initialize; @x=1; end; 
  def f; @y=1; end; 
end
```

the expression

```
AA.new.instance_variables
```

would return `[:@x]` - the :@y is missing, because it doesn't exist yet.

You don't have a way to automatically (i.e. without modifying the class) retrieve local variables. As *mudasobwa* explained in his answer, you would have to explictly pass back a binding.

Comment: `but in the example, you mention only instance- and class-variables.` Really? :) What are `a = 33` and `a = 3`, then, if not local variables?

Comment: Even though your answer might be valuable for other readers, but definitely not for OP, since for him, quote: *"it's pretty straightforward to get the instance and class variables dynamically, even the local variable inside the constructor. [...] But I'm stumped as to how to get the local variables `a=3`."*. So effectively, this answer has nothing to do with the question :)

Comment: Indeed! If this was present in the original question and not added later, I definitely have not seen it! It is correct, I missed the point completely!!

Answer (score 0):

One might get an access to all the local variables of the class by returning it’s binding from the class definition (see [`Binding#local_variables`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Binding.html#method-i-local_variables) for details):

```
a = class A
  v1 = 3.14
  v2 = 42
  binding
end

a.local_variable_get(:v1)
#⇒ 3.14
a.local_variable_get(:v2)
#⇒ 42
```

But the main question is why would you want to do that? The *local* variable is meant to remain *local*. This is how it is supposed to behave. Also, one is unable to modify the local variable in the original `binding` (what is returned is a read-only copy of an original binding.)

Comment: I wonder why the exercise says "Could you get the values from outside the class A?" and "Write your code which outputs like this:" I suppose it implies not changing the class definition, which makes the task impossible AFAIKT.

Comment: @AndreyDeineko well, it’s possible with NIF reading the stack :) These exercises are outdated (2009) and are in general looking like not the best source for exercises at all.

Comment: @mudasobwa : What is NIF? Didn't find it on Google. But IMO it doesn't make sense to ask for the value of local variables which might or might not spring into existence, when seeing the class from the outside, i.e without actually executing a method. The variables don't exist by themselves, and asking for their value is meaningless.

Comment: @user1934428 It’s also known as [FFI](https://spin.atomicobject.com/2013/02/15/ffi-foreign-function-interfaces/) and stands for Native Function Interface. Yes, it makes not much sense to try to discover locals from the outside..